# Maximize window with widgets Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have previously set a minimum window size in my program in Tkinter with the following:

```
win1.update()                                         # Update window
win1.minsize(win1.winfo_width(), win1.winfo_height()) # Minimum size of contents
win1.mainloop()
```

However, I would like to adjust the size of the window by dragging in the corner/maximize buttno with all widgets (labels, frames etc) to be maxmized with it. Is there a way of doing this similar to the method above?

Or is it more complicated and something has to be applied to each widgets separately?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest looking at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4785856/how-do-i-achieve-the-following-tkinter-gui-layout-with-either-pack-or-grid) I asked regarding my checkers game. I had much the same issue with getting widgets to adjust properly when I resized or maximized my window. The code example from [Bryan Oakley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7432/bryan-oakley) should point you in the right direction.

Comment: If you are interested in the code for the actual game, [it's available here](https://code.google.com/p/raven-checkers/source/browse/). For some reason, it's very hard to find any open-source projects that show how to use Tkinter.